# Why am I getting a 404 error when hitting GA4 data api without client library

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I need to pull GA4 data into client webpages.  The site I am working on is written in Coldfusion, so I am not using a client library.  The most recent Data API
[Migrating to the Google Analytics Data API v1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4#not_using_a_client_library) gives this URL to use without a client library;

> https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta.

I am getting a 404 error when I POST JSON to

```
https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/XXXXXXXX:runReport
```

Has the URL changed?

I am passing in the OAuth access token in the header.  I would expect to get a not authorized error if the error was authentication, so it seems that the auth is working.  This is the exact error I am getting

> "The requested URL /v1beta/properties/XXXXXXXX:runReport was not found on this server. That’s all we know."  The status code is 404

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: Have you tried v1 as opposed to v1beta ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] I would like to see how you are taking into account the gRPC transcoding.

Comment: @WarrenBurton are you sure there is a v1?  As far as i know this api is still in beta.  I have not heard anything about a full release yet Do you have a link?  [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport)

Comment: @WarrenBurton  This is the link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4#not_using_a_client_library

Comment: @DaImTo  Here is the code to create the JSON; it's Coldfusion   

<!--- build JSON for POST --->
  <cfscript>
    myStruct = {viewId = "#get_Analytics.Profile_ID#",pageSize=4000,dateRanges={startDate = "#DateFormat(Date_Start,'yyyy-mm-dd')#",endDate="#DateFormat(Date_End,'yyyy-mm-dd')#"},dimensions={name="ga:medium"},metrics={expression="ga:visits"}};

    jsonText=serializeJSON(myStruct);
  </cfscript>

Then I post using this code

Comment: @DaImTo 

Then I post using this code:
<cfhttp url="https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/341881471:runReport" method="post" timeout="15">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="OAuth #access_token#">
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="reportRequests" value="#jsonText#">
  </cfhttp>

Comment: Please **EDIT** your question and include [example]  don't just put it in a comment i cant run that.    What I can read though doesn't look anything like a GA4 report it looks like a UA reporting api report.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help someone.

I was having this same problem and realized that I was using GET instead of using POST.

Make sure you are using the POST request type instead of the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you fully read the [Migration guide for not using a client libary](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4#not_using_a_client_library)  Did you miss this section?

[image]

From what I can see if your code from your comments it looks like you haven't converted things over to GA4 properly.  For example you apear to be using a UA metric ga:medium, as well as you still have a viewId in there.

You may want to scan though [data api basics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#http)

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID:runReport
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
  {
    "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-09-01", "endDate": "2020-09-15" }],
    "dimensions": [{ "name": "country" }],
    "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }]
  }
```